# How to use jQuery with phantomjs

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I'm trying to do a simple test of jQuery with phantomjs:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/';
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function () {
    page.injectJs('jquery.min.js');
    page.evaluate(function () {
        console.log($('title').text());
    });
    phantom.exit()
});
```

This should print out the title, but instead nothing happens. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page.evaluate` executes your function in the page context, not in the PhantomJS context. So, everything that uses `console` will be printed (and will be visible) only for current Web Page instance.

To redirect the `console` output, you must use `onConsoleMessage` callback.

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/';
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.open(url, function () {
    page.injectJs('jquery.min.js');
    page.evaluate(function () {
        console.log($('title').text());
    });
    phantom.exit()
});
```

Reference: [onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html)

Comment: Thanks, this got me past it.

Comment: Amazing response :) .

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're missing `#` to target element by `id`:

```
console.log($('#title').text());
// -----       ^ add here
```

if `title` is a class then you can use `.`:

```
console.log($('.title').text());
```

Comment: No, title is the title tag. It's the thing that's most likely to be there, I'm just trying to demonstrate working jquery.